# How to automatically build CSS inside a ddev project using node-sass scss in a sidecar container?

Tags: ddev

I have a Drupal project where I would like to use Node.js build scripts to compile SCSS into CSS.

Answer (score 12):

I use a separate sidecar container that constantly watches for changes to SCSS in my Drupal theme and builds the CSS.

I have a `.ddev/docker-compose.sass-watch.yaml` file with the following:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  sass-watch:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-sass-watch
    image: node:12
    user: $DDEV_UID:$DDEV_GID
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../drupal/web/themes/custom/MY_THEME
        target: /app
        consistency: cached
      - ".:/mnt/ddev_config:ro"
    working_dir: /app
    command: ["sh", "-c", "npm i && npm run watch"]
```

Then inside my theme directory I have a `package.json` as follows:

```
{
  "name": "MY_THEME",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node-sass scss -o css --output-style compressed",
    "watch": "node-sass scss -o css --output-style compressed --source-map true -w"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  }
}
```

The `watch` command runs permanently in the background while my ddev project is running.

I can also use `ddev logs -s sass-watch` to get the output from the watch command if the build doesn't look like it has worked for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`node-sass` is no longer maintained and has an issue where it doesn't pick up new filenames while watching. Here's an updated version of Dave's answer that uses the more current "dart sass":

docker-composer.*.yaml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  sass-watch:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-sass-watch
    image: node:12
    user: $DDEV_UID:$DDEV_GID
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../drupal/web/themes/custom/MY_THEME
        target: /app
      - ".:/mnt/ddev_config:ro"
    working_dir: /app
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "npm i &&  npm run watch" ]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MY_THEME",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "sass scss css",
    "watch": "sass scss:css -w"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.49.8"
  }
}
```

You can, of course, tweak package.json as needed.